# Does CPath perform reference counting?

Tags: c++, winapi, c-strings, atl

I was wondering whether ATL's `CPath` behaves like the underlying `CString`, in that an assignment will result in a ref count rather than a deep copy. I don't see anything in the docs about it, and I'm not sure how to test it.  Here's some source that may be relevant, though I'm not sure:

```
template< typename StringType >
class CPathT
{
public:
    typedef typename StringType::XCHAR XCHAR;
    typedef typename StringType::PCXSTR PCXSTR;
    typedef typename StringType::PXSTR PXSTR;

public:
    CPathT() throw()
    {
    }
    CPathT(_In_ const CPathT< StringType >& path) :
        m_strPath( path.m_strPath )
    {
    }
    CPathT(_In_z_ PCXSTR pszPath) :
        m_strPath( pszPath )
    {
    }

    operator const StringType& () const throw()
    {
        return m_strPath;
    }
    operator StringType& () throw()
    {
        return m_strPath;
    }
    operator PCXSTR() const throw()
    {
        return m_strPath;
    }
    
    ...

public:
    StringType m_strPath;
};

typedef CPathT< CString > CPath;
```

Thank you very much for any info.

Comment: what type is `m_strPath`? Also show all data members. And as methods only copy constructor/copy assignment is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you showed in the code above, the `CPath` is just a wrapper for `CString`, so it encapsulates all its properties and behavior. Logically, it uses `CString` [reference counting](https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/cstring-in-a-nutshell/).